# Ignore certain string in list of split string while splitting in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

I need to split string in given lines based on list of string given. For this I use list of string to split line value and it works perfectly fine for most of the case but not for some of them.

As list of split string contains string which is substring of other string in same list.

For e.g.

I have following line values as

1. **mr lawrence j shryane estate of lawrence j shryane**
2. **the estate of ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence**

Following list of string is given for splitting string

```
List<string> lstSplitWords = new List<string>()
{
    "the estate of",
    "estate of",
    "in trust",
    "or"
};
```

Split code:

```
List<string> values = line.ToLower()
                          .Split(lstSplitWords.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Select(x => x.Trim())
                          .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

Following output is coming after executing split code

For line 1: **mr lawrence j shryane estate of lawrence j shryane**

```
values[0] // mr lawrence j shryane
values[1] // lawrence j shryane
```

This output is correct

For line 2: **the estate of ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence**

```
values[0] // the
values[1] // ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence
```

This output is incorrect

Correct output for this line is

```
values[0] // the estate of ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence
```

Not able to figure out how to tackle this problem as this is happening because lstSplitWords list has both **the estate of** and **estate of** string.

Is there any way that i can do this without hard coding the code?

Comment: I dont get two strings as result but just one: `ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jEQHE8 So clarify why you expect the full input-text instead of just the part after `the estate of`

Comment: the first delimiter `the estate of` will divide the string and only output with trim you can get is `ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence`. the delimiter is never returned in the split output so can't expect the output to be `the estate of ms. wilma m smart stone lodge residence`

Comment: You cannot have you split string and eat it too. You first say "abc split on b returns a,c and it is correct" and then you say "abc split on b returns a,c and it is NOT correct". Make up your mind; C# did exactly what you told it, in exactly the same way, and you said the first time was correct and the second time wasn't, but there is absolutely no difference between the two

Comment: 1. Your incorrect output is not what happens. 2. Your correct output is incorrect. 3. `String.Split` attempts to match separators in order in the array, so `the estate of` would match first. Please update question to be correct.